# What is the meaning of the word 'navitis' in the second edition of 'Introducing html5'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word 'navitis' shows up a lot in the book *Introducing html5*, and I didn't find it in a dictionary.

The sentences are:

> - 'I was previously guilty of navitis—the urge to surround any links to other parts of a site as <nav>.'
> - 'When tempted to use a “fat footer,” consider whether such links actually need <nav> at all—navitis can be hard to shake off.'

Comment: Can you give an example. I mean a sentence where this word is used.

Comment: *ish* -itis and *itis* -itis are endemic!

Comment: Your first example includes a definition, so what's your question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would take this almost certainly to mean **"overuse of the <nav> tag"**.  [The suffix -itis](http://wordinfo.info/unit/1100/ip:5/il%3aI) comes from the Greek language and is taken to mean "inflammation of" in modern English.  However, in an idiomatic sense, adding *-itis* to a word means that the author believes that the action is being done too often.  In this case, the author is referring to the overuse of the new <nav> tag, like it is a disease.

Answer (score 7):

The author defines the term in the very sentence you quote:

> I was previously guilty of navitis—*the urge to surround any links to other parts of a site as <nav>*.

The author is using a standard form for definition of an unfamiliar or coined word in context.

Answer (score 6):

I guess that *navitis* is a word the author invented to mean "too many  tags".  He probably defines exactly what he means in one of the early chapters.  E.g.:

> Just look at all those  sections.  It's so ugly!  This is what I call *navitis*.

*-itis* is an informal / humorous suffix which means "disease / illness".  (In formal usage, it's a medical suffix that means "inflammation".)  So he's describing a "disease" of website design.